# Where are all of these Office 365 questions coming from?

Tags: discussion, questions

It seems that in the last week, there's been quite an increase in the number of questions about Microsoft Office 365 products. (Excel Online, Outlook on the Web, etc.)

Don't get me wrong; I think it's a good thing. We need more questions about those web applications. (I am chagrined, however, that I can't really answer any of them as I don't use the products.)

I'm just wondering if there is a reason why. Did Microsoft include this site in some online documentation?

Comment: I couldn't find anything obvious from the [Site Analytics/Referrers](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) (10k+ only).

Comment: 25K EXP only there on the site analytics